Create cronjob to rrestart firewalld service every minute on RHEL 8
I'm trying to create a simple cronjob to restart firewalld service every minute. So here's what I do but it is not working
# crontab -e

* * * * *    root     systemctl restart firewalld.service

Then after a few minutes I run
# systemctl status firewalld.service

But I see that the last time the service was restarted hasn't changed.
What am I doing wrong?

As in the question that this is a duplicate of: You should not include the username as the 6th field in the schedule in personal crontab schedules.  When you user crontab -e as root, you are editing the root user's personal crontab.
